# Using Jquery Methods to change a div's CSS position from absolute to fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website where I have a div class called "menu-bar". It's just a bar that stretches across a few hundred pixels below the top of the screen with some background color. I have my HTML, CSS, and JQuery in 3 seperate files.

When a user scrolls down the page and when the top of the "menu-bar" reaches the top of the screen, I want it to stick there until the user scrolls all the way back up to its original position. Right now, the "menu-bar" is set to an absolute CSS position. I figured I could just use the JQuery methods .removeClass() and .addClass() to change the menu-bar's position to "fixed". Here's my code below.

Relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="page-container">
       <div id="header">
          <div class="menu-bar"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
   .menu-bar
   {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        top: 225px;
        background-color: #11342D;
        z-index: -1;
   }

   .menu-fixed {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #11342D;
        z-index: -1;
   }
```

The Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var offset = $('menu-bar').offset();

        $(window).scroll(function){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if offset.top < scroll) $('menu-bar').removeClass('menu-bar').addClass('menu-fixed');
            else $('menu-bar').removeClass('menu-fixed').addClass('menu-bar');
        });
    });
```

The code isn't working and I've been troubleshooting for days. What am I doing wrong? Here's a link to a site which has almost exactly the kind of behavior i'm looking for: [https://monocle.com/][1]

Thanks.

UPDATE: Below is the working jQuery code for anyone needing to replicate this behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var offset = $('.menu-bar').offset();

        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (offset.top < scroll) 
                {
                     $('.menu-bar').removeClass('menu-bar').addClass('menu-fixed');
                }   
            else 
                {
                     $('.menu-fixed').removeClass('menu-fixed').addClass('menu-bar');
                }    
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition syntax isn't correct, also `menu-bar` is a class, so use `.menu-bar`

```
if (offset.top < scroll)  //start ( bracket was missing
{
   $('.menu-bar').removeClass('menu-bar').addClass('menu-fixed');
}
else 
{
   $('.menu-bar').removeClass('menu-fixed').addClass('menu-bar');
}
```

you can also do

```
$('.menu-bar').toggleClass('menu-fixed', (offset.top < scroll) );
$('.menu-fixed').toggleClass('menu-bar', !(offset.top < scroll) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I know HTML and CSS, I just started learning jquery yesterday through the API documentation on jquery.com. I was missing one additional bracket  "(" on the second "function()". Would you mind explaining to me your second way of writing the last bit? Are you saying that could be added instead of the If Else statement? I'm assuming the "," is equivalent to saying WHEN evaluates to TRUE, and the "!" is equivalent to saying WHEN evaluates to FALSE?